# Lars algorithm with lasso modification

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, least-squares

I'm trying to implement the lars algorithm with the lasso modification.

[image]

At point 3. I'm stuck, I want to program it but I don't really understand it.

Point 1 and 2 I already did, here is the code:

```
#1. Standardize the predictors to have mean zero and unit norm.
set.seed(19875)  
n <- 10  
p <- 5  
real_p <- 5  
x <- matrix(rnorm(n*p), nrow=n, ncol=p)
x <- x-matrix(apply(x,2,mean),ncol=ncol(x),nrow=nrow(x),byrow=T)
x <- x/matrix(apply(x,2,sd),ncol=ncol(x),nrow=nrow(x),byrow=T)
y <- apply(x[,1:real_p], 1, sum) + rnorm(n)

#Start with the residual r = y − y ¯, β1,β2,... ,βp = 0
r=y-mean(y)
beta=matrix(0, ncol=ncol(x), nrow=1)
#2. Find the predictor xj most correlated with r.
co= t(x)%*%r
j= (1:ncol(x))[abs(co)==max(abs(co))][1]

#3. Move βj from 0 towards its least-squares coefficient xj,ri, until some
#other competitor xk has as much correlation with the current residual
#as does xj.
```

I would very much appreciate any clarification.

Comment: *"lars algorithm with the lasso modification"* Just to clarify & nitpick: LARS is a method to solve the L1-regularised least-squares problem (i.e. the LASSO problem). You are aware that Trevor Hastie & Brad Efron are the authors of R package [`lars`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lars/index.html), which does exactly what you're after?

Comment: @MauritsEvers Yes I know that, but I want to implement it without using the lars package